# Should I make this 1 question or 2?

Tags: discussion

I am currently almost done forming a question I just came across. As I was typing it up, I kind of figured out why my problem **might** be why it is. So I started to type my theory as to why I am getting this problem in detail.

I am looking for 2 things in my question

- Is my theory correct?
- What is the programming definition of a language that allows what I did (that is apparently an issue in Java)

For the second part, I am looking for something like `Co-variance` or some definition like that.

My question is, should I split this into 2 questions?

- 1 My problem with me answering my own question
- A link to #1 with the question asking what the programming definition would be

Or should I just leave it as one question?

Right now, I am thinking I should just leave it as one question, and later split it into 2 different question.

Comment: I guess this is just up to you. If you can say *"if my theory is correct, what is the programming definition of a language that allows what I did?"*, so that's fine, if both requires detailed explanation and high level of clarification, so better separate.

Comment: Note that, while I don't use - or often visit - [programmers.se], the way you describe your question sounds more likely to fall under their remit (or possibly that of [cs.se]) than [so], given that it doesn't *appear* to be about solving a specific problem; but more about theory and information about a concept (though that may be necessary to *solve* a, or the, problem).

Comment: Thank you both. @DavidThomas yes, i can definitely see that now. I think 1 question is theory, and the other is  Stack Overflow specific. I will see what others think

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this Meta.SE question and its answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for guidance on which site each question will be a good fit for.